# Training multiple Keras models in one script

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to train different Keras models (or in some cases just multiple runs of the same model to compare the results) in a queue (using TensorFlow as the backend if that matters). In my current setup I create and fit all of these models in one big python script, e.g. (in a simplified way):

```
for i in range(10):
    model = create_model(i)
    model.compile(...)
    model.fit(...)
    some_function_to_save_model(model)
```

The `create_model(i)` function creates the specific model for the `i`'th run. This includes changing the number of inputs / labels for example. The compile function can be different (e.g. different optimizer) for each run as well.

While this code works for me and I have not found any problems, I am unclear if this is the correct way to do it because all of the models reside in the same TensorFlow Graph (if I understand the way Keras / TensorFlow work together correctly). My questions are:

1. is this the correct way to run multiple **independent** models. (I do not want any influence of the `i`'th run on the `i+1`'th run)
2. is running the models from different python scripts (in this example model1.py, model2.py, ... model9.py) in any way better **technically speaking** (I am not referring to readability / reproducibility here) because each model would then have its own separate TensorFlow Graph / Session?
3. Does clearing the Session / deleting the Graph via `keras.backend.clear_session()` have any influence in this case if it is run after the save function (`some_function_to_save_model()` inside the `for` loop)? Is this in some way beneficial compared to the current setup?

Once again: I am not concerned with the problems that might arise due to creating messy code if all models are cramped together in one script instead of a single script per model only with creating & training models independently.

Unfortunately I did not find a concise answer to this (only suggestions using both methods). Maybe someone here can enlighten me?

Edit: Maybe I should be more precise. Basically I would like to have a technical explanation regarding the differences (advantages & disadvantages) of the following three cases:

1. create_and_train.py:

   ```
   for i in range(10):
       model = create_model(i)
       model.compile(...)
       model.fit(...)
       some_function_to_save_model(model)
   ```
2. create_and_train.py:

   ```
   for i in range(10):
       model = create_model(i)
       model.compile(...)
       model.fit(...)
       some_function_to_save_model(model)
       # clear session:
       keras.backend.clear_session()
   ```
3. create_and_train_i.py with i in [0, 1, ..., 9]:

   ```
   i = 5 # (e.g.)
   model = create_model(i)
   model.compile(...)
   model.fit(...)
   some_function_to_save_model(model)
   ```

   and e.g. a bash script that loops through these

Comment: Dude no response yet?